# htaccess Convert https://www. to non www

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to convert urls to https://example.com

I managed to convert the following:

```
http://www.example.com

http://example.com
```

but not:

```
https://www.example.com
```

My code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that was a no go. Also for some reason the first code set works fine in all instances in Chrome but not in Safari or Firefox (even after clearing the cache and restarting the apps).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add ```RewriteBase /``` before the condition ```RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]```.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work either.